# Compound interest with certain probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have three values about a certain investment scenario:

- The expected return per anno in %
- The maximum gain per anno in % that will not be exceeded with a probability of 95%
- The maximum loss per anno in % that will not be exceeded with a probability of 95%

I want to create a chart from these values showing the expected return over the next 10 years and also the expected interval that will not be left with a probability of 90% for each year. [This](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sastraining/files/2013/12/un_population_graphs41.png) is a chart showing different data but roughly what it should look like.

To calculate the line for the expected return (the middle one) over the next years I used a simple compound interest calculation, starting with 100% (as my chart will show percentage values). So given the expected return p.a. $r$, for the expected return $r_x$ after $x$ years is use

$$r_x = (1 + \frac{r}{100})^x * 100\% - 100\%$$

This yields reasonable results and I'm confident this is the correct way. However, I tried the same for the maximum gain (upper line) and this gave me crazy high numbers. Thinking more about it, it makes sense to me, as calculating the gain after $x$ years with the maximum gain that will not be exceeded with a probability of 95% each year, ultimately yields a value that will not be exceeded with a probability of $(1 - 0.05^x) * 100\%$. The same goes for the maximum loss of course.

What I would want to calculate is for each year the maximum gain (and maximum loss) with a probability of 95%. Is it possible to calculate this from the values I have? If yes, how?

I tried to find a solution for this on google but due to my lack of knowledge regarding statistics I seem to not find the propper search terms or find sources that I don't fully understand.

Comment: You're looking for the prediction interval, not to be confused with the confidence interval. See Wiki for reference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval

Comment: Thank you, knowing that term is very helpful and that link was a good start for further research. However, I'm still struggling with how to calculate the prediction interval from the values that I have.

Comment: Wikipedia laid out different scenarios. Do you know the mean and/or variance of $r$? Or neither? I don't know what you have available.

Comment: I really only have the three values I mention in my answer. As I calculate the value of the expected return I essentially have the mean for every year, but I don't know the variance, I just have the 90% confidence interval for the first year. What I tried now is calculating an estimate for the standard deviation from this first confidence interval and then calculate the prediction interval from this estimate and the mean value.

I used the explanations and formulas from here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/prediction-intervals.html